# C++ Concept, how to check a constexpr static int is equal to 1, or similar...? Clang disagrees with GCC and MSVC

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, c++-concepts

I can't find the correct syntax on [cpprefference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for a concept that matches the **value** of a `static constexpr` member. This code compiles, and functions correctly on GCC and MSVC, but does not work in Clang. I was wondering if anybody knew if this was my mistake, or an issue with either GCC and MSVC or Clang?
Here's a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYjdeAAdUIUJzWjtHF2UomLM6Hz9ApxCwziNMEzTaBgJmYgIE51d3Y0xTOJKyggyA4NDwo1LyyqS8oS7m31bs9s4ASiNUB2JkDikdAGZfZEcsAGpNBZs0WlmIgiFN7E0ZAEFF5dXMDa3zfuJMZicjk/OzgkwnCNUPzZsCACeESsT2uABUXmcdnsCGsALIAuy7TD7G4AETWDwAjg48A8hGsIGC1gQxpoAOz6M5rGmYzA4vGYAkEAB0Tk%2BOXRmwxnE2VPO5LRfNer3uDlMawYG0pr1pax2/Uw4gixDW/WYZmQa18sPZI1VFN02gpQoW/JNwrOYolGMNstpCo%2BytV6s12voaz1nMNvMFloFpvN70%2B3w1mD%2BCKRMLWEIWxzOADdUHh0GsqA5dhAyTLqbT%2BugQCgprC/n8NtptE4NcgEJh0JoAKw2Wg6Y1mkV%2Bs6vHWe5i%2BLN23M09O7P6m7AD9tDukEaa0NYyf0Ws5SCasaQN%2BSuWTyVDSGwGAxqqYza6LTjyAjSORjCYAazcDZU0m4W%2Bvu%2Bk8iEIBkpCvO4mOBYBgRAiy%2BPB2DICgIDQcDIJABNkAiCIAH0E04ABOFDtCwgA1BhOAANhQzgZBQ8QAA5CL4CCPmIb8ICCd9SCCXwygBaQL1IWD2XoAB5WhWA4ndSCwKt1HYZj8AeeoEyZZilTqBwPk4%2BQdQKZjWDwIJiHYuwsGYghiDwJxVImKhVGAIRcLwTAAHc%2BOBbcuP4RgWEkng%2BDoAhhDESQRKUPJVHUFBDz0FRtO/SAJlQfY4m/KQAHp81CvQDB%2BJlYUSvjxC/Ao6iKSxrB6VxuDyTwWiyHIuAWUgUliOgSpAMq6uiBraEqtpclq2p6joRpunsKpmr6fK%2BuKAZOv1GrOiaJqWvVcopuqzgFgmIQT1mLg1w3N8RL3KRKMIz0hEQtZ0IwlkcLWfCiJZUjCVwQgSHLBY8jWOw4NCV7xg%2BsLdEvd9b1IWtmCwMIs1IB9tCfdcpFfUhTIbX9tzkUgDq/H8/yB0ggNA4sImU8hKFgiIINGDx8CIXIvPoJg2A4Th3Fc3yJGYuzdIiMznykTdSFRj8pD45TCdhVAqDWI6TrOi6rowm6CMI%2B6ZEJT6ycgn6xkBgCJlB8HKB2%2BH5CRlHmIxowsf/G970fHmFj2tHzat1dcZAvGICQUnyagknUC%2BsIVjUYAUKMjM7xo1g6IYpiRNY2h2NU7i/d4ggBKEqTPiDySROkgq8DkhK0cU5BlLmNH1LhtGtJ0vSMDLy9jNMqQL3MyzrNshynMT1z6Y83gWZENmArcFQg9S/RwurqLIdiooEoAWj4hY1nn/NuS0NK9G0NHesKiBPCa8rrGWin6qKQ/WtSOIT5p3eGgGC%2B7/6yahiqinFoqIbelmpbX667bJjTC2uMHmfMBbo2kEdeehFuDymCsAQkodaB3jGI9KmL1zykA%2Bn7dW31FjaFQQeTeANsY6yhrbOGCMTb8zNp%2BC2v5naATdkgAmRNoJe3gu4Osz0aY93cozZm3lWb%2BTRhzZgXNm4uzhmA2hQsRbKTWOLSWVFoGwMDuoRBxAw6oIgGrb2r0CHa2tiDR4%2BtIaUONiAZGND9p0O/AwoGNsYZ2wdoLIxLt3bMLArgn2MEcHexAMATgTMI5R0oDHNGccE6SKTk4FOadhJozElneuolGSyXkiJYupdmIV00tpXSxBER10Mo3bmFlmBWRsvZRyVhu7eV7ozfuQjB4iPkEoWq8Dx4GAikEaeMU4p0AXkvFea8Fhog3hPI0O8xp7wPl/VwR9vB/2mnkM%2BcQL7rPSCsla%2BRCj3zmgs5QT8JpNBvsch%2BRy%2Bgv0yP/EBG0gGM0NjI2xh0VEwLWMAZAWpglXTQTwn6WC9Ea0WGtP6xD3HA2hrDF8ljrHgPNvY0hN5XbwA9iAVhBBiZ%2BP9iAWq3DqbKD4QzLggjBCtPZpzbm0jXEQLkQQUWiiJZQI%2BV8n5nA/m6P8SC7QCw1qQt1qY9o5jYWIysabV5mMHFkOhS4mxjs6GMMNtoWlTtHGkDkvROIzUgA) with all three compilers open, I think it illustrates the point!

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires (T t){
    requires t.member == 1;

    //[clang's error]
    // note: because 't.member == 1' would be invalid: 
    //       constraint variable 't' cannot be used in an evaluated context
};

struct S {
    constexpr static int member {2};
};
struct D {
    constexpr static int member {1};
};

template<MyConcept T>
void func(){
    std::cout << "matched\n";
}

int main(){
    func<D>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang is correct here (thanks, Casey).

[[expr.prim.req.nested]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.nested)/2 says:

> A local parameter shall only appear as an unevaluated operand within the *constraint-expression*.

And [[expr.ref]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref) says:

> A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`, optionally followed by the keyword template, and then followed by an *id-expression*, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;55 the result of that evaluation, together with the id-expression, determines the result of the entire postfix expression.

In `t.member`, that evaluates `t`, and we're not allowed to do that in this context.

A different way to express this would be to drop the *requirement-body* entirely and check the static member directly:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = T::member == 1;
```

Concept definitions are arbitrary boolean expressions, so this is sufficient and doesn't run afoul of any rules.

Comment: I think clang is correct. [expr.ref]/1 says that `t` is evaluated when evaluating `t.member`; there is no exception for the case where `member` is a static member of `t`'s class.

Comment: [class.static.general]/1 reiterates the evaluation also